# Swift - UICollectionView spacing issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need assistance on how to properly set spacing and insets for UICollectionViewCells I did not found any questions related so I figured to just ask.

I want to achieve the following result (note that the spacing between cells is evenly distributed):
[image]

But what I currently have is this (next row of cells can also be seen, along with the top spacing not the same as bottom spacing):
[image]

Below is my code:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 15
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`minimumLineSpacing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/minimumLineSpacing) only influences the minimum spacing between successive rows (for vertically scrolling grids) or successive columns (for horizontally scrolling grids). You'll also need its counterpart, [`minimumInteritemSpacing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/minimumInteritemSpacing).

I can't tell you what the exact values must be, you'll have to play around a bit.